# How to get an expand-popup while pressing UITabbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar, uibarbuttonitem

I don't know if this is asked before or if I'm phrasing the question correctly. I can't find any information on google neither.

My question is: How do I get a sort of popup like [this](http://tapbots.com/img/software/tweetbot/icon_tabbar.png) when I press a tabbarbutton?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out something about `NSPopUpButton`. I think a bit of experimenting on that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is nothing built into the sdk that gives you this out-of-the-box.  So you'll have to build it yourself.  Maybe start by showing a simple view with some buttons in it when the user taps the tab bar. Base this view's frame on which tab bar button was chosen. You'll need to detect taps inside (to choose an item) and outside (to dismiss the pop-up) when the user wants to do something else.